# Mocking return value of method that returns Kotlin Coroutines Deferred type

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, retrofit, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm using Kotlin Coroutines and in particular using Retrofit's `CoroutineCallAdapterFactory`.  I'm trying then to unit test a class that in turn utilizes Retrofit interface (`GalwayBusService` below).

```
interface GalwayBusService {

    @GET("/routes/{route_id}.json")
    fun getStops(@Path("route_id") routeId: String) : Deferred<GetStopsResponse>

}
```

In my unit test I have

`val galwayBusService = mock()`

and then trying something like following to mock what gets returned when that method is called.  The issue is though that `getStops` returns a `Deferred` value.  Is there any particular approach recommend for mocking APIs like this?

```
`when`(galwayBusService.getBusStops()).thenReturn(busStopsResponse)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The proper solution is to use [`CompletableDeferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-completable-deferred/).
It is better than writing `async` because it doesn't launch anything concurrently (otherwise your test timings may become unstable) and gives you more control over what happens in what order.

For example, you can write it as `whenever(galwayBusService. getBusStops()).thenReturn(CompletableDeferred(busStopsResponse))` if you want to unconditionally return completed deferred or

```
val deferred = CompletableDeferred<GetStopsResponse>()
whenever(galwayBusService.getBusStops()).thenReturn(deferred)
// Here you can complete deferred whenever you want
```

if you want to complete it later

Answer (score 4):

So, turns out the way to do this is to use `async` as below:

```
whenever(galwayBusService. getBusStops()).thenReturn(async { busStopsResponse })
```

Credit btw to https://twitter.com/_rafaeltoledo for the answer!